# school assignment regarding inverting Dictionary with Tuple[Keys] and string[values], writing to text file

Tags: python, json, dictionary, tuples

inverting Dictionary with Tuple[Keys] and string[values], writing dictionary to a text file, then reading the text file, and inverting the keys-values back to original order.

I'm just `<json - .dumps/.loads>` to convert the data to a string to save, and then back into a dictionary.  The problem is that I'm getting an error code trying to invert the values and keys back... my error is

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Here is my code:

```
import json

def invert_roster(d):
     inverse = dict()
     for key in d:
          val = d[key]
          if val not in inverse:
               inverse[val] = [key]
          else:
               inverse[val].append(key)
     return inverse 

a = 0
def choice(c):
    a = ' '
    choice = input('Enter <add> to add to file, or <view> to view file.')
    if choice == 'add':
        add(a)
    elif choice == 'view':
        view_file(a)

def add(a):
    rf = 0
    choice2 = input('<new> File or <old> File?')
    if choice2 == 'new':
        new_file()
    elif choice2 =='old':
        read_file(rf)
    roster = dict()   
    name = ' '
    print('Enter <stop> to exit.')
    while name != 'stop':

        name = input('Enter first and last name of patient: ')
        if name == 'stop':
            write_file(roster)
        diagnosis = input('Enter Diagnosis of patient: ')
        first,last  = name.split(' ')
        roster[last, first] = (diagnosis)

def write_file(roster):
    print(roster)
    file = open('journal8.txt', 'w')
    ir = invert_roster(roster)
    print(ir)
    wf = json.dumps(ir)
    file.write(wf)
    file.close()
    choice()

def view_file(a):
    file = open('journal8.txt', 'r+')
    vf = (read_file(file))
    print(vf)
    keys = vf.keys()
    print(keys)
    print(type(vf))
    for c in vf:
        print(c, vf[c])
    for c in vf:
        vf[c] = tuple(vf[c])
    print(vf)
    ta = json.dumps(vf)
    invert = invert_roster(ta)
    file.close()
    return()

def read_file(rf):
    line = rf.readline()
    fin = line.strip()
    rf = json.loads(fin)
    return(rf)


def new_file():
    file = open('journal8.txt', 'w')
    return()


choice(a)
```

The issue seems to be in f(x)=view_file and f(x)=invert_roster. I'm able to convert to string and write to file, read the file and manipulate data from the file, but I can't invert the darn thing.

Comment: you can say `for key, val in d:` instead of `for key in d:
          val = d[key]`

Comment: @muyustan do you think that's the problem?  the invert function was given verbetum by the textbook so I didn't tinker with it.  what does `key, val in d:` do?  is it iterating both key and val over d?  the comma confused me...

Comment: no, no I haven't looked to the problem in general, I was just skimming and saw that, wanted to point out it can be done in that way also. `for key, val in d:` iterates over keys of the dictionary and at the same time, val is assigned to the value of that key.